# Sail.js - How to create a clean log file?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm currently using `Sails v0.10.0-rc7` and tried to forward the console logs into a file.
Some older threads described a way to do this by adding the following lines to the `config/log.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    log: {
        level: 'info',
        filePath: 'someFile.log'
    }
};
```

But this doesn't seem to work anymore.
Sails uses the subproject [captains-log](https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log) which formerly encapsulated winston. According to the README.md I changed the `config/log.js` to:

```
var winston = require('winston');
module.exports = {
    'log': {
        'custom': new (winston.Logger)({
            'transports': [
                new (winston.transports.Console)({
                    'level': 'info',
                    'colorize': true,
                    'timestamp': false,
                    'json': false
                }),
                new winston.transports.File({
                    'level': 'debug',
                    'colorize': false,
                    'timestamp': true,
                    'json': true,
                    'filename': './logs/test.log',
                    'maxsize': 5120000,
                    'maxFiles': 3
                })
            ]
        })
    }
};
```

Well, that works, but the logged messages always have a colored prefix within the message text. So the output in the console looks like

```
info: info:
info: info:
info: info:    Sails              <|
info: info:    v0.10.0-rc7         |\
info: info:                       /|.\
info: info:                      / || \
info: info:                    ,'  |'  \
info: info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info: info:                 `--'-------'
info: info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info: info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: info:
```

(with both info tags colored in green) 
and the log file messages look like

```
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m   Sails              <|","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m   v0.10.0-rc7         |\\","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m                      /|.\\","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m                     / || \\","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.517Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m                   ,'  |'  \\","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m                .-'.-==|/_--'","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m                `--'-------' ","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m   __---___--___---___--___---___--___","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m","timestamp":"2014-07-02T10:51:13.527Z"}
```

Working in production mode supresses the prefixes, but I still have some color codings in the log messages.

So, does anybody have an idea how to get rid of the prefixes and color codings in the log messages?

Comment: I was able to accomplish my goal by adding `colors: false` besides the `custom: ...` entry.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others can find it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by adding `colors: false`:

```
var winston = require('winston');
module.exports = {
    'log': {
        'colors': false,
        'custom': new (winston.Logger)({
            'transports': [
                new (winston.transports.Console)({
                    'level': 'info',
                    'colorize': true,
                    'timestamp': false,
                    'json': false
                }),
                new winston.transports.File({
                    'level': 'debug',
                    'colorize': false,
                    'timestamp': true,
                    'json': true,
                    'filename': './logs/test.log',
                    'maxsize': 5120000,
                    'maxFiles': 3
                })
            ]
        })
    }
};
```